# Catch User 'Allow/Deny' Response on Computer Location Query

Tags: javascript, browser, geolocation, geoip, maxmind

I am using [MaxMind GeoIP2 JavaScript API](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/) to determine a user's location when they enter my website. This prompts the user for their permission to provide the location via the browser. I am using this information to load as the default position of a map I have on my website.

I was wondering if there is some capture for this Allow/Deny prompt click. For example, the map loads  the default position if the user were to deny the request, but if there user hasn't made a choice until after the map loads, I'd like to relocate the map if they do happen to click Allow once the browser has loaded the website.

For what it is worth, here is some example code that gets the users information once permission is given (taken from the URL above):

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="//j.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.0/geoip2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var onSuccess = function(location){
    alert(
      "Lookup successful:\n\n" + JSON.stringify(location, undefined, 4)
    );
  };

  var onError = function(error){
    alert(
      "Error:\n\n" + JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 4)
    );
  };

  geoip2.city(onSuccess, onError);

</script>
```

Comment: You could pay for the service and then pass the `w3cGeolocationDisabled` flag.

Comment: I haven't used this API before, but it looks like the `onSuccess` callback would get called when the user clicks "Allow", and the `onError` callback would get called if the user clicks "Deny".

Comment: @camerondm9 I could be wrong, as I can't see any different, but it seems like that function only checks whether or not the user has allowed or not historically and not an actually on trigger

Comment: @oschwald This is an option, yes, but am more interested in finding this prompt response as I believe the user should be aware if they are being geolocated.